# Simplifying code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this following code

```
$j(document).ready(function(){
    $j('#uang').on({
        focus: function(){
            var ini = $j( this );
            var theVal = accounting.unformat( ini.val() , ',' );
            var data = ( theVal == 0 ? '' : theVal);

            ini.val( data ).select();
        },
        focusout: function(){
            var ini = $j( this );
            var kembalian = $j('#kembalian');

            var val = accounting.unformat( ini.val() , ',' );
            var cicilan_val = $j('#cicilan');
            var cicilan = accounting.unformat( cicilan_val.val() , ',');
            if( val > 0 ){
                var nilai_kembalian = val - cicilan;
                kembalian.val( accounting.formatNumber( nilai_kembalian ) );
            }
        },
        keyup: function(){
            var ini = $j( this );
            var kembalian = $j('#kembalian');

            var val = accounting.unformat( ini.val() , ',' );
            var cicilan_val = $j('#cicilan');
            var cicilan = accounting.unformat( cicilan_val.val() , ',');

            if( val > 0 ){
                var nilai_kembalian = val - cicilan;
                kembalian.val( accounting.formatNumber( nilai_kembalian ) );
            }
        }
    });
});
```

It runs well. But the one that disturbs me is the repetitive part. Notice that `focusout` and `keyup` have the same code. Can I simplify it without using function()?

1. I've tried something like `keyup, focusout: function(){`, but it doesn't work.
2. How/ Where can I write `var ini = $j( this );` once but I could access it inside any methods (actions??), i.e. inside focus, focusout, etc.

Thank you.

Comment: you can create a helper funciton with a name and then do keyup: myNewFunction and the same with focusout

Comment: `Can I simplify it without using function()?` Why do you wish to not use function?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @GeraldSchneider well, I just heard if there is such a site :3 Sorry..

Comment: @user3008011 nothing. I'd like to have another alternatives, since I just knew using `function`.

Comment: You can merge `focusout` and `keyup` like this `"focusout keyup": function() ....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not willing to use function() then this could be an option -

```
$j(document).ready(function(){
    $j('#uang').on('focus', function(){
            var ini = $j( this );
            var theVal = accounting.unformat( ini.val() , ',' );
            var data = ( theVal == 0 ? '' : theVal);

            ini.val( data ).select();
      }).on('focusout keyup', function(){
            var ini = $j( this );
            var kembalian = $j('#kembalian');

            var val = accounting.unformat( ini.val() , ',' );
            var cicilan_val = $j('#cicilan');
            var cicilan = accounting.unformat( cicilan_val.val() , ',');
            if( val > 0 ){
                var nilai_kembalian = val - cicilan;
                kembalian.val( accounting.formatNumber( nilai_kembalian ) );
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: event types should be separated by space

Comment: @tarmaq Yup sorry, typo.. fixed it...

Comment: There is no need for multiple `on()` calls. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but try something like that.

```
    $j(document).ready(function(){
        var myfunction = function(){
                var ini = $j( this );
                var kembalian = $j('#kembalian');

                var val = accounting.unformat( ini.val() , ',' );
                var cicilan_val = $j('#cicilan');
                var cicilan = accounting.unformat( cicilan_val.val() , ',');

                if( val > 0 ){
                    var nilai_kembalian = val - cicilan;
                    kembalian.val( accounting.formatNumber( nilai_kembalian ) );
                }
            };
        $j('#uang').on({
            focus: function(){
                var ini = $j( this );
                var theVal = accounting.unformat( ini.val() , ',' );
                var data = ( theVal == 0 ? '' : theVal);

                ini.val( data ).select();
            },
            focusout: myfunction,
            keyup: myfunction
        });
    });
```

Comment: it not works because we didn't get current this

Comment: @sudharsan: What do you mean, "we didn't get current this"?

Comment: var ini = $j( this ); this object

Comment: @sudharsan: that's not true. In both cases is `$('@uang')` in `ini` variable

Comment: @sudharsan: it has to work the scope will be passed to the function and the this will be correct.

Comment: @ius : It works. I've tried it.. :) Thanks for the code..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$j(document).ready(function(){

    $j('#uang').on({
        focus: function(){
            var ini = $j( this );
            var theVal = accounting.unformat( ini.val() , ',' );
            var data = ( theVal == 0 ? '' : theVal);

            ini.val( data ).select();
        }
    });

   $j('#uang').on('focusout, keyup', function(){
            var ini = $j( this );
            var kembalian = $j('#kembalian');

            var val = accounting.unformat( ini.val() , ',' );
            var cicilan_val = $j('#cicilan');
            var cicilan = accounting.unformat( cicilan_val.val() , ',');
            if( val > 0 ){
                var nilai_kembalian = val - cicilan;
                kembalian.val( accounting.formatNumber( nilai_kembalian ) );
            }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is much simpler than the accepted answer.

1. For adding the same listener to multiple events, use

   ```
   'keyup focusout': function() { ... }
   ```

   in the object literal.
2. For reusing the variable `ini`, declare it in the outer function as follows:

   ```
   $j(document).ready(function(){
       var ini = $j('#uang');
       ini.on({ ... });
   });
   ```

   The handlers will have access to the variable even after the outer function returns because JavaScript has closures.